# 90s Mixed sci-fi and fantasy medieval show where the villain is captured and he went insane

Tags: story-identification, tv, medieval

When I was a kid I watched a TV show (late 90s, early 00s). All I can remember was some stuff from the episodes that I watched. It was in English.

The TV show had a medieval setting with swords, shields, armor and other stuff from that period. Some of the main characters had "modern" outfits. There was war between the good guys and the bad guys. There was a villain, and when the good guys captured him he went insane.

The show also had magic, I think + some weird weapons and vehicles that were more science fiction.

It was a live-action show, not a cartoon. I don't remember any of the characters.

Comment: Do you have any more details? Even obvious ones like - cartoon or real life? Main characters? Anything more specific?

Comment: This is all fairly generic — medieval setting, some anachronistic elements. Can you remember something that might be unique to the show? What kind of magic was there? Did it turn out to be magic or advanced technology? Was there time travel? Was it our past history, alternate history, a fictional world?

Comment: Also, what country was this in?  Lots of small things can help, like if it was on prime-time or in the afternoons, the network (or syndicated), or any other details.

Comment: Only thing that springs to mind is Neverwhere (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neverwhere). As the others have said, more details might help.

Comment: 1997 to 2002 was a really deep and wide pool of fantasy on TV. We need more to go on.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52996/what-tv-show-british-i-think-in-the-90s-had-knights-and-helicopters-guns?rq=1

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189711/old-movie-about-a-group-of-friends-with-magical-weapons-fighting-monsters (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like [*Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mystic_Knights_of_Tir_Na_Nog), I also watched this show as a kid, in the same time period (1998-1999).

> Queen Maeve of Temra seeks to conquer the peaceful kingdom of Kells and enlists the evil fairy Mider, who gives her the mystical Rune Stone allowing Maeve to use sorcery, most often to create ogres and evil giants, whom she sends to wreak havoc. When King Conchobar of Kells seeks a way to protect his kingdom, protagonist Rohan, a druid's apprentice, goes in search of the prophesied hero 'Draganta', with his friend the reformed thief Angus. Later joined by the foreign Prince Ivar, and Conchobar's daughter, Princess Deirdre, they are drawn into Tir Na Nóg, whose king Fin Varra puts the group through various tests to determine their worthiness. The heroes having passed these tests, King Fin Varra gives them certain weapons granting control of the Classical Elements Fire, Air, Earth, and Water. Thereafter the four overcome Mider's 'Evil Sentinels' (recurring villains in the series) to capture corresponding suits of armor, and oppose the various monsters created by Maeve, assisted by the winged fairy 'Aideen'. Subsequently, Rohan gains a new partner in Pyre the dragon, who later identifies Rohan as Draganta.

Answer (score 1):

[*Spellbinder*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series))!

It's definitely set in a medieval world with some sci-fi components, like flying "space" vehicles. It's made in the early 90's, and the "medieval" people believes that the sci-fi parts are magic. Watch the trailer: 1:47.

> A group of teenagers go on a school camp in the Blue Mountains in Australia. While at the camp, Paul Reynolds accidentally goes into a parallel universe. This other world is inhabited by a more hierarchic and technologically different society, ruled by a group of people known as Spellbinders. Paul meets a girl there named Riana, and they become friends.
>
> [...]
>
> Paul is eventually able to travel back home, but he is forced to take Riana with him in order to save her. Later, when Paul is able to take Riana back home, the Spellbinder Ashka follows Paul as he later returns home. Ashka seeks the unwitting help of Paul's father in making her a new high-tech 'flying suit' to replace her power suit in order to make her more powerful than the other Spellbinders.
>
> However, Paul manages to expose her scheme and defeat Ashka, who is returned as an outcast to the Spellbinder world, while Riana becomes the new apprentice to Correon. In order to keep the Spellbinder world safe from the more advanced people from "modern" world, the gateway between the two universes is closed permanently.

Comment: I've edited to add some basic information about the series in here, could you [edit] to explain how this matches the OP's description?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly Elidor: 
This show haunted me for years

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Instead of just linking to an episode, you should also include a description of how it matches my n case the episode is taken down.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be [*The Lost World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_World_(TV_series))

> "At the dawn of the 20th century" a band of British adventurers, led by adventurer and scholar Professor George Challenger, embark on an expedition to prove the existence of an isolated lost world. The team, consisting of a mismatched group of enthusiasts with less than selfless reasons for making the journey, begin their trip under less than ideal conditions. The members are Challenger, Professor Arthur Summerlee, Marguerite Krux, Major Lord John Richard Roxton and Edward T. Malone.
>
> Their hot air balloon crashes in the Amazon rainforest on an uncharted plateau where prehistoric creatures survive. The group is assisted by a young jungle-savvy woman named Veronica Layton, whose parents disappeared eleven years before. Her family was part of a research group known to have vanished under mysterious circumstances. Together, the group fights to survive against carnivorous dinosaurs, vicious Neanderthals, a race of lizard men, and other perils as they search for a way to escape. Each episode detailed two separate, simultaneous adventures.

Comment: This, as it stands, is hardly an answer.  At least give some details (other than the link, which might go dead) why you think it matches the question.

Comment: ....6 years later...