# What TV show (British I think) in the 90's had knights and helicopters/guns?

Tags: story-identification, tv, medieval

There was a TV show I used to watch, I don't remember much about it, except it was in a medieval setting (knights, castles, etc.), except one faction(?) had black helicopters and guns.

What was this show??

Comment: Are you sure about the knights? (I have an idea, otherwise.) 90s would exclude a Doctor Who episode...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Knights of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_God)?

> Knights of God was a British science fiction children's television serial, produced by TVS and first broadcast on ITV in 1987. [...]
>
> In 2020, **Britain is ruled by the Knights of God**, a fascist religious order - founded by the Prior Mordrin (Woodvine) - that came to power during a brutal civil war in the year 2000, during which the Royal Family were supposedly all slaughtered by Hugo (Fellowes). Mordrin has renamed the south of England "Anglia", while the north and Scotland - which has only now been brought under control - he calls "Northumbria." In between is the "Wasteland", where the remaining resistance fighters - labelled "terrorists" by Mordrin - are still at large. Winchester is the new capital, as most of London was destroyed in the war.
>
> Gervase Owen Edwards (Winter) has grown up in Wales, which has finally succumbed to the rule of the Knights, although the resistance led by his father, Owen (Thomas), still operates. [...] Unknown to Gervase, Mordrin needs Julia alive as well, as she is the daughter of Brigadier Clarke, the senior officer in the **Coldstream Guards, the last remnant of the British Army**, which has been allowed to survive for ceremonial purposes. [...] one surviving member of the Royal Family - a King to unite the country against the Knights.